# setTimeout inside a function

Tags: javascript

```js
function delay2sec(){
  let name = "abc"
  setTimeout(function () {
    name = "xyz"
  }, 0)

  return name
}

console.log(delay2sec())
```

The output is abc.

Can someone explain why it is not reassigning the name to 'xyz'?

Comment: `Can someone please explain why it is not reassigning the name to 'xyz'?` It does reassign it, but that code happens *after* everything else, so it's not very useful. You create name = 'abc', then you set a timeout, then you return 'abc', then you log 'abc'. Later on, the timeout goes off and you assign 'xyz'.

Comment: I think the problem here is likely not understanding that Javascript is mostly synchronous, and non-blocking, so the code execution doesn't _wait_ for that setTimeout to resolve, and instead continues to the return - This is what async / await is used for -- There should be lots of resources to explain this concept, but here's the first I found to point in the right direction https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand this behavior, you need to understand how the event loop works:

[image]

Your `setTimeout` adds an event to the event loop, which will be executed after the current function. Your `return` statement is evaluated before the current function ends, so the `return` evaluates the value **before** the change.